# qsort does nothing with cmpstr

Tags: c, sorting, qsort

I'm not sure why qsort doesn't change my array because the elements aren't in alphabetical order. Can someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
char **wordlist = malloc(sizeof(char*));
int i, numwords = 0;
wordlist[0] = strdup(words[0]);

for(i = 0; i < wcount; i++)
{
    wordlist = realloc(wordlist, (numwords+1)*sizeof(char *));
    wordlist[numwords] = strdup(words[i]);
    numwords++;
}

printf("Added %d words to the array and they are:\n", numwords);
for(i = 0; i < numwords; i++)
{
    printf("%s\n", wordlist[i]);
}

qsort(wordlist, numwords, sizeof(char *), cmpstr);

for(i = 0; i < numwords; i++)
{
    printf("%s\n", wordlist[i]);
}

int cmpstr(const void* a, const void* b)
{
   const char* aa = (const char*)a;
   const char* bb = (const char*)b;
   return strcmp(aa, bb);
}
```

Comment: The `realloc` is wrong. You should do `realloc(wordlist, (numwords+2)*sizeof(char *));`

Comment: Please provide the code of `cmpstr()`. It's important.

Comment: `wordlist[0]` is assigned twice.  `wordlist[0] = strdup(words[0]);` and first `wordlist[numwords] = strdup(words[i]);`.  Thus losing first allocation.

Comment: Wrong compare function.  `a` and `b` **point** to `const char *`

Comment: Not a knock, but generally when you say "*A well tested C-library function behaves wrong*"... it's not the function that is to blame. You are looking for `return strcmp (*(char * const *)a, *(char * const *)b);`

Comment: No need for first allocation.  `char **wordlist = malloc(sizeof(char*)); ...
wordlist[0] = strdup(words[0]);` --> `char **wordlist = NULL;`

Answer (score 2):

Your comparison is wrong:

```
int cmpstr(const void* a, const void* b) {
    char *aa = * (char * const *)a;
    char *bb = * (char * const *)b;
//             ^
//       asterisk here!
//
    return strcmp(aa, bb);
}
```

`a` and `b` are **pointer-to-pointers**.

Or alternatively:

```
int cmpstr(const void* a, const void* b) {
    char * const * aa = a;
    char * const * bb = b;
    return strcmp(*aa, *bb);
}
```

Also, there's a potential memory leak because you didn't `free()` what `strdup()` gives. You should remove Line 3 in your given code:

```
wordlist[0] = strdup(words[0]);
```

Comment: when I change it to that it gives me the warning "initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]" and it still doesn't sort the array

Comment: @McLovinIt Did you notice there's an asterisk after the value assign operator?

Comment: I got it working with the suggestion that @DavidC.Rankin posted that has now been deleted

Comment: @McLovinIt I suppose both should work. They are essentially the same.

Comment: @iBug there is a difference, one is *type qualified* and one is a *pointer to const*, see [C11 Standard § (draft n1570)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5) and see [Note: 29](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p29)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I got you. I remember [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Qualification_conversions).

Comment: You are doing better than I am. I always remember there is an issue there, but have to look it up again to remember which way it goes `:)`

Comment: `char * const * aa = a;` --> well done!